# In the review queue, getting lots of edits as attempts to reply by an anonymous user.

Tags: discussion, editing

Lately, I'm seeing lots of attempts to reply by anonymous user. I strongly suspect it's just one anonymous user who's responsible. How can we handle this?

Answer (score 1):

That sort of [history](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history) should lead quickly to a ban on accepting edit suggested from that person.

Comment: Unfortunately, if the user is anonymous, there is no-one to ban.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Er, actually, there is. This can happen to an IP address. Or maybe it’s a cookie, but I think it an address.

Comment: It can only be done automatically, because there is no identifiable user, and the auto ban is only triggered if a number of suggestions are declined for **vandalism,** not for any other reason. (I don't know what that number is)

Comment: Excuse the curious newbie question, but if the mystery IP has not committed vandalism, as @Andrew implies he hasn't, then what has he done that you want to ban him?

Comment: @David A large number of edits adding comments or answers into the question. There's a specific "Attempt to answer or reply" rejection reason, which applied in this case. Nevertheless, it's definitely something which could usefully be stopped as it's disruptively not the right thing to do.